# example for 2 data with same sha256 sum

Tags: sha, sha256

Is there any example for data that has the same **sha256sum value**?

Or is it impossible to find out with current computational power?

Comment: The search term keyword you are looking for is a "collision" https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47809/why-havent-any-sha-256-collisions-been-found-yet

Comment: BTW, you asked the same question 12 months ago.